# Spring boot 2.1.x integration with Kafka 1.1.x

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

We are working on migration of existing spring boot application from 1.5.x to 2.1.x with Kafka integration.

As we are using Kafka 1.0.0 broker, we need to degrade Kafka client version to 1.1.1.So we degraded the client **(commented pom content)** but it fails to consume the messages after degrade. It works fine with **Kafka client 2.0.1** library.

The below is the pom file. Please help.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <name>demo</name>

    <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <relativePath/>
        <version>2.1.15.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka</artifactId>
      <!--<exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
          <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>-->
    </dependency>
    <!--<dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
      <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>-->
  </dependencies>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
        <scope>import</scope>
        <type>pom</type>
        <version>Greenwich.SR1</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

Consumer code :

```
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListener;
import org.springframework.messaging.Message;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class KafkaConsumer {

  @KafkaListener(topics = "test.topic", groupId = "test.group")
  public void consume(Message message) {
    System.out.println(message);
  }
}
```

yml file details

```
spring:
  kafka:
    consumer:
      bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092
      group-id: test.group
      auto-offset-reset: earliest
      key-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
      value-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
    producer:
      bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092
      key-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
      value-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
logging:
  level:
    root: INFO
```

Documents referred

```
https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/wiki/Kafka-Client-Compatibility
https://spring.io/projects/spring-kafka
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to downgrade; you can use newer kafka-clients with older brokers for a long time now.

Comment: With newer Kafka client SSL validation is failing. Looks like there is no backward compatibility. That's the reason we wanted to downgrade. Do we need to follow any steps for SSL validation to pass with newer Kafka client version?

Comment: I am not aware of any such issues; you might be better off asking on the [user mailing list](https://kafka.apache.org/contact).

Comment: @GaryRussell Does your statement apply to major breaking versions? i.e, kafka-clients 3.x against kafka-broker 2.x

Comment: In general, yes; the only issue I am aware of is with transactions; the the 3.x.x clients will no longer fall back to EOSMode V1 (aka ALPHA) when talking to a broker older than 2.5; spring-kafka is configured to use V2 (BETA) by default so you have to switch the mode. https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.8.4-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/#x28-kafka-client (or fall back to the 2.8.1 clients). The 3.0.x clients have deprecated the API and spring-kafka 3.x and later (due towards the end of this year) won't support V1 w/brokers older than 2.5  (we could revisit that if there is sufficient demand).